# Adding special character to a column names

Tags: python, regex, list, python-re

I have a list of column names that are in string format like below:

```
lst = ["plug", "plug+wallet", "wallet-phone"]
```

I want to add `df[]` along with `" ' ".`
I am using regex to substitute it. But the regex which I am using works fine when the list is like this:-

```
lst = [" 'plug'", "'plug'+'wallet'", "'wallet'-'phone'"]
x=[]
for l in lst: x.append(re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'df[\1]',l))
print(x)
```

the result is as excepted

```
x: [" df['plug']", "df['plug']+df['wallet']", "df['wallet']-df['phone']"]
```

But when list is like this:

```
lst = ["plug", "plug+wallet", "wallet-phone"]
x=[]
y=[]
for l in lst: x.append(re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'\1',l))
for f in x:    y.append(re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'df[\1]',f))
print(x)
print(y)
```

This gives:

```
['plug', 'plug+wallet', 'wallet-phone']
['plug', 'plug+wallet', 'wallet-phone']
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I missing anything in the first regex pattern or not passing the `r'\1'` properly?

Excepted Output:

```
x: [" 'plug'", "'plug'+'wallet'", "'wallet'-'phone'"]    
y: [" df['plug']", "df['plug']+df['wallet']", "df['wallet']-df['phone']"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import re
lst = ["plug", "plug+wallet", "wallet-phone"]
x = [re.sub(r"([^+\-*\/'\d]+)", r"'\1'", l) for l in lst]
y = [re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r"df[\1]", l) for l in x]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Your first regular expression was wrongly matching on the `''` and was then in the replace subject not enclosing it in `''`.

Tested under Python 3.8.0.

Comment: Just one more doubt. When list values have (wallet-phone). Then the result would be df[('wallet'] - df[('phone'], what would be the best solution for this to convert (df['wallet']-df['phone']). I was trying to get a pattern that does but couldn't find the best solution.